# javascript verification html register form ,but no response

Tags: javascript

Today I am going to use JavaScript to do a validation of the registration page, but after an afternoon of verification, the function can be called. When the test pop-up window is added at the beginning of the function, the pop-up window pops up correctly, but the verification function in the function is always unresponsive. Ask for the forum's amnesty, where is the problem, thank you! ! !

I added a test popup statement to the script and it succeeded. But other functions don't respond.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>注册界面</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/register.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.alert("test");

      function checkRegisterINfo(form) {
        /*判断姓名格式是否正确*/
        var RegisterNameCheck = document.getElementById("nameId").value;
        if (RegisterNameCheck = "") {
          window.alert("姓名不能为空！");
          return false;
        } else {
          var rightName = /[\u4E00-\u9FA5]{2,16}/;
          if (rigntName.test(RegisterNameCheck) == true) {} else {
            window.alert("您输入的姓名不正确！");
            return false;
          }
        }
        /*判断密码是否规范*/
        var RegisterPwdCheck = document.getElementById("pwdId").value;
        var rightPwd = /^(\w){6,20}$/;
        if (rightPwd.test(RegisterPwdCheck) == false) {
          window.alert("密码只能输入6-20个字母、数字、下划线");
          return false;
        }
        /*判断密保问题格式是否正确*/
        var RegisterQuestionCheck = document.getElementById("questionId").value;
        var rightQuestion = /[\u4E00-\u9FA5]{1,16}/;
        if (!rightQuestion.test(RegisterQuestionCheck)) {
          window.alert("密保问题支持1-16位汉字！");
          return false;
        }
        /*判断密保答案格式是否正确*/
        var RegisterAnswerCheck = document.getElementById("answerId").value;
        var rightAnswer = /[\u4E00-\u9FA5]{1,50}/;
        if (!rightAnswer.test(RegisterAnswerCheck)) {
          window.alert("密保答案支持1-50位汉字！");
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="title">
        <span>用户注册</span>
      </div>
      <form name="registerForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkRegisterINfo(registerForm)">
        <!--输入框-->
        <div class="input-content">
          <div>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="nameId" placeholder="用户名" name="Registerusername" required/>
          </div>

          <div style="margin-top: 16px">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" id="pwdId" placeholder="登录密码" name="Registerpassword" required maxlength="32" />
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: 16px">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="questionId" placeholder="密保问题" name="Registerquestion" required maxlength="32" />
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: 16px">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="answerId" placeholder="密保答案" name="Registeranswer" required maxlength="32" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--登入按钮-->
        <div style="margin-top: 105px">
          <button type="submit" class="enter-btn">登录</button>
        </div>

        <div class="foor">
          <div class="left"><span>忘记密码</span></div>

          <div class="right"><span>用户登录</span></div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: `rigntName` !== `rightName` - the error shows in the console. Simple fix.

Comment: You are really cool, and solved the problem that bothered me for an afternoon. But after I made the transformation, the value of "rightName" is 2-16 Chinese characters, but when I input two Chinese characters, the pop-up window is still an error, why?